# Calculating dynamic pricing on Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, cumulative-sum, gs-vlookup

I have imported data from a trading exchange listing sellers of a particular cryptocurrency.

From this data, I want to create dynamic pricing to display an average cost on an order based on given order size.

I will give an example of what I am looking for:

Example dataset

[image: 0]

Within this example, we would be purchasing the cryptocurrency 'SINS'. As per the data showed on this table, if 29.06 SINS was purchased, that would fill the first order, and the total BTC paid would be 0.00459 BTC.

If an order was placed for 145 SINS, it would fill the orders up to row 12 and partially fill the order in row 13. By calculating that manually, I know that would cost 0.02293365 BTC (calculated using col D) at an average price of 0.00015816 per SIN.

What I would like to achieve is if a number is entered in a cell, it confirms the average price of an order based on the number entered and the orders imported from the trading exchange.

Comment: The sheet is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1loxlCHvLesgs-OyWnLUiGkktKfBt4lQFmKezJJlZp2M/edit?usp=sharing

Please bare in mind the data pulled from the IMPORTHTML will be different from the above screenshot, however what I am trying to achieve is the same.

Comment: Hi @player0 . I don't suppose you have managed to look in to this?

Comment: actually, I did, but even with your instructions included in your question, I have no idea what exactly are you after.

Comment: I have provided more information on the spreadsheet, and hopefully this makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: let's see if I understood it... H2 should be sum of x values from column C that is equal or lower than 1500 and cell i2 the average of column D of corresponding range. is that right?

Comment: H2 should be the sum of Col D for values where the sum of column C is equal to or less than 1500 (or whatever figure is shown in G2). I2 could simply be H2/G2. I have created a new tab with a fixed table (dataset) and examples of results to demonstrate the result if that order amount was placed in G2 on Sheet 1 (and assuming the dataset on Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 are the same, which they are not because Sheet 1 dataset is using an IMPORTHTML function).

Comment: hmm... which cells did you sum to get **H2** to be `0.0071315800256082` ? I can figure it out the rest if I would just know how to filter it

Comment: First of all I worked out how much of the orders a purchase of 100 coins would fill. So it would fill the order in C2 and then 78.2330% (61.1/78.1) of C3. Therefore 0.0071315800256082 is D2 + (D3*0.78233).

Comment: Hi @player0 . I am wondering if I can have some follow up advise. On the same file, I have a list with different data, however the calculations are not correct on this second dataset. I believe it is because of the numbers in the ADDRESS function. Could you help with it?

Comment: should be correct like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qG38I.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(VLOOKUP(O2,F2:F,1),F:F,0),7,4))+(
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(VLOOKUP(O2,F2:F,1),F:F,0)+1,4,4))*(O2-
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(VLOOKUP(O2,F2:F,1),F:F,0),6,4)))/
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(VLOOKUP(O2,F2:F,1),F:F,0)+1,3,4)))
```

[image: 0]

---

**[spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uMpWw8ftS4upMj2R4gHNF4YPRQXipUroWz3L1OVNlgQ/edit#gid=142081498&range=J2)**